# Dismissing view and routing to root view after successful login for PFUser

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am having trouble to dismiss the PFLoginView after successful login. It appears that the login is successful, however the view is not dismissing itself and routing to the root view. Below is my LoginViewController, subclassing from PFLoginViewController:

```
class LoginViewController: PFLogInViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}

func logInViewController(controller: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) -> Void {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
}
```

I'd appreciate it if someone with experience with ParseUI.framework could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out. Zisoft thanks for your attempt. I tried your answer, but it was not dismissing the viewController. Here is the code for you to replicate it:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //Create Login
    var loginViewController:PFLogInViewController = PFLogInViewController()
    loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.Default
    presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    loginViewController.delegate = self
    loginViewController.signUpController.delegate = self
}

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didLogInUser user: PFUser!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

func logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn(controller: PFLogInViewController) -> Void {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
}
```

What is different this time is that I am not just subclassing PFLoginViewController, but I am creating the PFLoginView within my LoginViewController. Then I am dismissing the view and then simply using routing to the root view.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`popToRootViewController` automatically dismisses the current viewController, so it should be sufficient:

```
func logInViewController(controller: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) -> Void {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```